# How to get data from database and create a dynamic select?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Im trying  to create a select which is dynamic, for example if there is 3 item in the database gift, then it will create 3 select with value from the database lecturer. This is the javascript to create the select when the user click the button add.
Now after the user have create 3 select and submit it, if the user wish to edit back the data, how can I do it ?

```
function addField(area,field,limit) 
{
var field_area = document.getElementById(area);
var all_inputs = field_area.getElementsByTagName("select"); 
var last_item = all_inputs.length - 1;
var last = all_inputs[last_item].id;

if(document.createElement) 
{ 
var li = document.createElement("li");
    var input = document.createElement("select");
    var opt = document.createElement("option")

    input.id = field;
    input.name = field;
    opt.value = "NULL";
    opt.textContent = "NO LECTURER";
    li.id = "li"+last_item;

    input.appendChild(opt);
    li.appendChild(input)
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $.ajax
    ({
    type:"post",
    url: "event/data.php",
            success: function(data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        $(input).append(data);
    }
    });
    });
    field_area.appendChild(li);


    } 

    }
```

Here example of what I have create,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkBxK.png

Here how it works

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTPrT.png

So basically in the database have 5 data, so what im trying to do is in the next page it will automatic create the exact 5 select. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function (useful for reuse)

```
// Returns select dropdown
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
function create_select($name='select', $values = array(), $current='')
{
    $select = '
    <select name="'.$name.'">';
    foreach($values as $key => $value){
        $selected = $key == $current ? ' selected = "selected"' : "";
        $select .= '
        <option value="'.$key.'"'.$selected.'>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    $select .= '
    </select>
    ';
    return $select;
}
```

and call it:

```
// $options : return array from DB
$curr = 'some_key';
$select_name = 'my_select';

echo create_select($select_name,$options,$curr);
```

**A complete working example:**

[image]

```
<?php
// Returns select dropdown
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
function create_select($name='select', $values = array(), $current='')
{
    $select = '
    <select name="'.$name.'">';
    foreach($values as $key => $value){
        $selected = $key == $current ? ' selected = "selected"' : "";
        $select .= '
        <option value="'.$key.'"'.$selected.'>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    $select .= '
    </select>
    ';
    return $select;
}
        $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = '';

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
        if(!$conn )
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db('effone_db');
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $options[$row['option']] = $row['option_value'];
        }

        echo create_select('settings',$options,'100');
?>
```

Comment: so the $values should be the data from the database right ?

Comment: Thats the default of function, no need to bother it, copy paste as is. $options is the data array you have to concern about, when you call the function. Remember using this function the array keys will be option value and array values will be option text.

Comment: So technically the function create a select with values from database right?
So what if from totalRows_somedatabase has 3 then how can I use this to automatically create 3 select ?
So I just pass totalRows to the function and create a looping ?

Comment: Run your query through database and get the values in array (say: $options = array('20' => 'Twenty', '30' => 'Thirty', '40' => 'Forty'); and pass the array $options through the function. It will produce <select name='select'><option value='20'>Twenty</option><option value='30'>Thirty</option><option value='40'>Forty</option></select>

Comment: Added picture for what I have done, really man thanks just another problem

Comment: You want 5 separate select dropdown to be created? What is the table structure?

Comment: From your function you know add the looping maybe, is it possible ? but the amount of select is based on totalRows of a table.
Like while(something) then it goes to your select,

Comment: You have to make the conditional filter after fetching data and create separate arrays for as many select drop you want and call the function with separate parameters that many times or make a multidimensional array and run foreach. I'm still thinking why you need all those drops? How many options they will hold? A table structure is really required for better understanding.

Comment: I dont think I find other options so I just used your methods . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that **$options** holds the resulting query.

So what you must do is loop thru the items and echo them inside a `<select>` tag.

like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select name='nameUrSelectHere'>
            <?php
                foreach($options as $option){
                    echo "<option value='" . $option['column_one'] . "'>" . $option['column_two'] . "</option>" ;
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```